# Quick way to see if all checkboxes are unselected

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jpanel

I have a java JPanel with 16 JCheckBoxes and I am wanting to ensure that the user selects at least one before submitting the form. The only way I know to do this is a huge if statement that looks at the Boolean value of the "isSelected()" method, but this seems inefficient. 
So I was wondering if there was a faster to way to check if all of the boxes are unchecked.

Comment: Right, and I have a listener. I was wondering if there was a quicker way to check the boolean using the listeners. I do not want to go through and check every button.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an `if` statement. You can do it with a big logical expression using `||`:

```
boolean somethingChecked = box1.isSelected()
    || box2.isSelected()
    || ...;
```

or, if the boxes are in an array (much preferred), a loop:

```
boolean somethingSelected = false;
for (JCheckBox box : boxes) {
    if (box.isSelected()) {
        somethingSelected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an [`ItemListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) attached to each `JCheckBox` to track the count of checked boxes:

```
int selectionCount;
ItemListener boxListener = new ItemListener() {
    @Override public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            selectionCount++;
        } else {
            selectionCount--;
        }
    }
};
```

(Note that if this is all that the `ItemListener` is doing, a single instance can be attached to all the boxes.) The `selectionCount` should be initialized to the number of boxes initially checked. Then at the appropriate point(s) in your code, you can simply test whether `selectionCount` is greater than zero.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick I believe:

```
 public boolean validatePanel(JPanel panel) {   
    for (Component component : panel.getComponents()) {
        if(component instanceof JCheckBox){
            JCheckBox c = (JCheckBox) component;
            if(c.isSelected()){
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That method receives a JPanel and get all the components on it. Then check all of then, if it's a checkbox will cast the Component to CheckBox to have access to `isSelected` method. If any checkbox is selected it will return true, if it finish the `foreach` without returning any true it means that no checkbox were selected.